# not getting push notification

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

After searching for 2 days applying solutions found on stackoverflow not able to fix the problem in my application. i am not getting push notifications in app. i am sending message from wordpress using wp gcm getting response from gcm server:

```
{"multicast_id":8254312412899412709,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1439464061399302%7e2c8c8ef9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1439464061399862%50b5570df9fd7ecd"}]}
```

in logcat it is showing

```
    08-13 15:36:50.752: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11517): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
    08-13 15:36:50.752: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11517): GCM IntentService class: com.itcombine.saidlist.GCMIntentService
    08-13 15:36:50.762: V/GCMBaseIntentService(11517): Acquiring wakelock
```

Below is my code:

GcmBroadcastReceiver:-

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "GcmBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    Log.d(TAG, "Got message");
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

GcmIntentService:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
String TAG = "Px GCM IntentService";
String newms;
public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "Got message: " + messageType + ", gcm=" + gcm.toString());

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // Post notification of received message.
            newms = extras.getString("message").toString();
            sendNotification("Received: " + newms);;
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString() + ", message=" + newms);
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    Log.d(TAG, "Done handling message");
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("alert", "1");
    intent.putExtra("msg",newms);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);

    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setSound(uri)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                  .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.itcombine.saidlist.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.itcombine.saidlist.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.itcombine.saidlist" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I found same problem in some other questions on SO but the solution which they have given is not working for me. As they have given that files should be in same package but i have only one package. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommands to not use WakefulBroadcastReceiver anymore but GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService on Android. Making this change may solve your problem

[source here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)